# Wordpress role is empty

Tags: wordpress, roles

happy Xmas and a happy New Year to all!

I'm trying to get the Wordpress role for a logged user but I'm getting an empty array. Notice that the user seems to be logged, as the first conditional doesn't get trigged.
Do somebody guess what could be happening?

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) 
{
    $user = new WP_User( $user_ID );
    if (!empty( $user->roles )) 
    {
        if(is_array($user->roles))
        {
            foreach ($user->roles as $role)
            echo $role;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Not array";   
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Is empty";    
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Not logged";  
}
```

Comment: i tryed in my local installation and it has printed correctly 'administrator'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that the $user_ID you're passing into WP_User() is not set.  Depending on the context this may or may not be set.  You might be able to obtain it by inserting in the line above:

```
global $user_ID;
```

That would definitely be the case if you're calling this from inside a function.

or to be sure, you could try:

```
$user_ID = get_current_user_id();
```